# Virial expansion of real gas equation and volume work

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory-of-gases, equation-of-state, isotherm

Hi I am currently working on a thermodynamics problem, and it asks me to first find the volume work done on a gas that behaves like the simplified Dieterici equation (see below) predicts on isothermal compression.

[image]

I already started working on it, but am not sure if it is correct; I started with the idea that the volume work done on a gas during compression is the negative integral of p over dV (Where Vi is the volume the gas started with and Vf the volume of the gas after the compression):

[image]

First of all; would that be the correct expression for the volume work? I am honestly not sure.

In the second part of the problem, it asks me to find the virial expansion of the first given equation (Dieterici equation) of p to quantify the difference of the volume work between an ideal gas vs a Dieterici gas. I am unsure how to do that, and why virial expansions even matter in this context. How would I even start with that?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: 1) That is not the Dieterici equation, since the Deiterici eqn. contains an exponential.   Rather, it is the first two terms of a Taylor expansion of the Dieterici equation about $T=\infty$.  I.e., it is an approximation of a Dieterici gas.  2) Even with that, it's still not quite correct to say your expression gives the work for that approximation of a Dieterici gas.    Rather, what you've derived is the correct expression for *the work done on a two-term series approximation of a Dieterici gas about $T=\infty$, when it undergoes a reversible and isothermal compression or expansion*.

Comment: 2)  Screenshots are discouraged, since they are not searchable.  It is encouraged that you instead use MathJax to show equations.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. Yeah it’s true that it’s about isothermal compression. You’re right, and how would I formulate the virial expansion for the simplified dieterici equation

Comment: I'll leave that to someone else, but I will say that, if you want an answer, you need to do three things:

1) Search this site to see if your question has already been at least partially answered, and include references to those answers in your post.
2) Show your own work on formulating a virial expansion as a starting point.
3) See my 2nd comment about screenshots.

Comment: You may find useful these links:
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [formulas/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) ( not to be applied to titles ) and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: What is your understanding of the general form of the virial expansion?